# How to set author name in comment in Word using VBA?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I have small Template for MS Word. I want to add comment with hyperlink. I can already add the comment with the following code, but I want to set the author name of that comment. I don't know how to do that.

Here is my working code: (author is not set currently)

```
URLText = "https:\\www.google.com"
Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
With Selection
        .TypeText (CommentText)                        'Add comment text
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, _     'Add hyperlink to comment
        Address:=URLText, _   
        ScreenTip:=URLText, _
        TextToDisplay:=URLText
End With
```

However I have tried by following code. Which set author name but I can't add hyperlink in my comment by this way:

```
Dim cmtMyComment As Comment
Dim link As Hyperlink
link.Address = URLText
link.ScreenTip = URLText
link.TextToDisplay = URLText


Set cmtMyComment = Selection.Comments.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, _
Text:=(CommentText)
cmtMyComment.Author = "ABC"
```

I didn't find property to set hyperlink.

Can anybody suggest me how to set author name? I have tried but didn't find any property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is an `Author` property which you can set like so and the hyperlink still works as you can see with the GIF below

```
Public Sub AddCommentWithLink()
    URLText = "https:\\www.google.com"
    Set Comment = Selection.Comments.Add(Range:=Selection.Range)
    Comment.Author = "Donald Duck"
    With Selection
            .TypeText (CommentText)
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
            Address:=URLText, _
            ScreenTip:=URLText, _
            TextToDisplay:=URLText
    End With
End Sub
```

Which will result in a comment like this

[image]

Comment: I know above functionality but I don't know how to add Hyperlink it it. can you update your code which include hyperlink in comment? That can help me.

Comment: Then please adjust your question as it points readers into the wrong direction ...

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my comment with other code.  I will be happy to change anything missing in question. Can you please suggest me if I am missing in question or in my code?

Comment: I just tested the code and it works - see the GIF; or do I still misunderstand your question?

Comment: I have seen your code. I have missed a line. Thank you.